# the script works in firefox and chrome but not in ie, jquery undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have a problem with Javascript, the script works fine on firefox and chrome but not in IE ( but works in IE in my local system problem occures when i uploading it on server )

am getting an error message from IE ' jQuery Undefined' could anybody please help, here is my code:

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style_custom.php">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="menu/css/simple_menu.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boxes/css/style5.css" />

 <!-- Google fonts -->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?   family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Playfair+Display:400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'  />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Terminal+Dosis' rel='stylesheet'   type='text/css' />
<!--JS FILES STARTS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.eislideshow.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
         <script>
        jQuery.noConflict()(function($){
            $('#ei-slider').eislideshow({
                                    animation                       : 'center',
                                    autoplay                        : true,
                                    slideshow_interval      : 3000,
                                    titlesFactor            : 0
            });
        });
    </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slides/slides.min.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cycle-slider/cycle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabify/jquery.tabify.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prettyPhoto/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/twitter/jquery.tweet.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrolltop/scrolltopcontrol.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/portfolio/filterable.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr/modernizr-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/kwicks/jquery.kwicks-1.5.1.pack.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject/swfobject.js"></script>
 <!-- get fancybox -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" itemprop="javascript"       href="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" media="all">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.2.1.js"></script>
 </head>
```

Comment: Did you upload jQuery to the server too? Or how are you including it?

Comment: please have a look on the complete code in pastebin : http://pastebin.com/E76kUCDJ

Comment: Please include entire code snippet which will give more pointers.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/E76kUCDJ  .. please have a look on it..

Comment: How are you running the page? Is it local or hosted in a server?

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be in the HTTP headers for the .js files, so check them using e.g. http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html and if the problem is there, fix the server settings. Another possible cause is that something happens to the .js files when they are uploaded, but this is less probable.

If this does not help, please post the URL of the page.

Comment: i have checked ..everything is fine please have a look on my website url.. http://unera.in

Comment: @user1969310, the page at the URL does not cause an error described in the question in IE 9. Instead, the console log reports syntax error in www.serversfree.com and an unknown error with `@font-face`.

Comment: thank you for checking it..actually i have corrected the error.. the error causing factor was script, i tried to encrypt the page using java script encryption. after encryption the page works fine in chrome and firefox but not in IE, it cant read the script... why IE is not recognizing java script encryption?..

Comment: @user1969310, that would depend in encryption being applied. There was no hint of any encryption in the question.

Comment: because i didn't notice that it is because of encryption so i didn't mention it..